# Android "com.android.internal.util.Predicate" deprecated

Tags: android

I just change my compile sdk version from 27 to 28 , after that am getting an issue because of deprication

**com.android.internal.util.Predicate**

as google developer forum say i changed it to **"java.util.function.Predicate "** but that time **apply()** is not working.

Is there any alternate function for apply()

Comment: I think the `java.util.function.Predicate` uses the method `test(T t)` instead of `apply`. So just use the `test()` method.

Comment: @Vall0n forusing test() minimum api level is 24 , its not possible mine is 19

Comment: @ashishdhiman2007 i didt get clear idea of how to use apply() after changing to java.util.function.Predicate

Comment: Is it possible to use your own interface instead of the `java.util.function.Predicate` but which contains basically the same?

Comment: @Vall0n can you give me a sample idea

Comment: What I meant is to copy the complete interface and save it to your code base and use that instead. [Here is the source code of the Predicate interface](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/function/Predicate.java)

Answer (score 0):

see the Java SE [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) ...it uses a type parameter & a functional interface:

> **Interface** `Predicate<T>`
>
> **Type Parameters**: `T` - the type of the input to the predicate
>
> **Functional Interface**: This is a functional interface and can therefore be used as the assignment target for a `lambda expression` or `method reference`.

as well as the warning in the Android SDK [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/internal/util/Predicate):

> This must not be used outside frameworks/base/test-runner.

for example:

```
Predicate<Integer> greaterThanTen = (i) -> i > 10; 
Predicate<Integer> lesserThanTwenty = (i) -> i < 20;  
boolean result = greaterThanTen.and(lesserThanTwenty).test(15);
```

rather complex methods assigned to the functional interface might provide more sense - because else, this is a quite complicated way of formulating this (without improving the readability too much):

```
boolean result = 15 > 10 && 15 < 20;
```